# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word: add caption to image in C#

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, office-interop

I create Word file in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
I insert image:

```
Word.InlineShape pictureShape = paragraph.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(img.Url, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

but I can't insert the caption for it.

I have tried to use:

```
 pictureShape.Range.InsertCaption("caption");
```

but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to work "as is" you will need an item in your caption collection called "caption". Try "Figure", which is one of Word's default labels, and see if that works.

To add custom caption labels to the caption collection you use the Word.CaptionLabels.Add function. And, you would do this first before trying to use the custom label in the InsertCaption method.

If you want the caption to read, "Figure # unique caption" then you use the Title property on the InsertCaption method and insert your unique caption there.

Here is an example, from an [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7a19005d-560d-4fca-ace8-922838403abf/adding-a-caption-to-an-image-insertted-using-c?forum=worddev), of adding your own custom label:

```
oWordApp.CaptionLabels.Add("Picture");
object caption = oWordApp.CaptionLabels["Picture"];
oWordApp.Selection.InsertCaption(ref caption, ref oLabel, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: it works nicely with "Figure" but when i tried to use Word.CaptionLabels.Add it tells "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or proparty 'CaptionLabels.Add(string)'. Could you help me little bit more with this?

Comment: @Seiggailion I have edited my answer to include an example of adding a custom label.